# Xamarin: ADB Binary is Obsolete

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

When I run (or first run) a Cross-Platform Android app in Visual Studio, I a message that the ADB Binary is obsolete and should be updated. Not sure from where.

[image: ADB Binary Issue]

Here are my installed tools:

[image]

I created a few starter apps and they work. Just not sure how to address this issue.

Also, when starting the app in VS I get this output:

```
[I:]:                     Looking for Android SDK...
[I:]:                       Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_70e59f45\Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
Path contains adb.EXE in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[I:]:                       Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_70e59f45\Android\AndroidSdkDirectory not found.
[I:]:                       Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\MonoAndroid\PrivateAndroidSdkPath not found.
[I:]:                       Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
[I:]:                       Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
```

RON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the SDK manager in Android studio (double shift and type SDK manager). Then on the second tab (SDK Tools) update the Android SDK Build-Tools and the error message should go away.

Comment: I did just that and this is the result. I mean, the apps work (very minimal apps) but...?

Comment: @Ron Click 'Tools' in the toolbar at the top, then click 'Options'. Make sure Android SDK Location is detected automatically, or change the path.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who was getting this error but the accepted answer was not working here is an alternative solution. For me I already had the latest SDK installed but was still getting this message. To fix it I used the SDK Manager to uninstall the Android SDK Platform-tools.

After you do this Visual Studio will immediately tell you that the SDK is not in a valid state and it will re-install the entire SDK. After it is finished you need to rebuild your project in order to launch your app.

Comment: This worked for me. Android Studio didn't notice or say anything after I uninstalled the SDK, but after I reinstalled it everything worked fine.